# How to find the particular solution of the differential equation using method of initial parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, classical-mechanics, greens-function

$$\begin{equation}
\frac{\text d^4w}{\text dy^4}-2\,(n\pi)^2\,\frac{\text d^2w}{\text dy^2}+\Big((n\pi)^4-
\alpha^4\Big)\,w=C_{n}\,\delta(y-\zeta)\\
\end{equation}$$

I am trying to find the particular integral of the above-mentioned differential equation. The objective is to find the green function by using this method. In one of the reference (cf. [1], from Eq. (14)) they explained first by extracting the homogenous solution $w$ and after that assuming some constants for the homogeneous solution $w$, and its 1st,2nd,3rd derivatives when evaluated at $y=0$, Now we have four equations for unknowns and solve for unknown coefficients. But it is not quite clear.  This derivation starts from Eq. (14) in [1], I understand till Eq. (38), after that i am pretty much lost.

---

[1] L.A. Bergman, J.K. Hall, G.G.G. Lueschen, D.M. McFarland: "Dynamic Green's functions for Levy plates", *J. Sound Vib.*  **162**-2 (1993), 281-310. [doi:10.1006/jsvi.1993.1119](https://doi.org/10.1006/jsvi.1993.1119)

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about, but Fouriertransform should do a pretty good job in solving this DE

Comment: Just want to extract the particular integral part of the differential equation using method of initial parameters

Comment: @YuriyS  Thanks.

Comment: What is that reference you mention? Could you give a link?

Comment: @YuriyS  https://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022460X83711193/1-s2.0-S0022460X83711193-main.pdf?_tid=3157c328-19e7-11e8-9a92-00000aacb360&acdnat=1519534327_3aa9d7fd2a7fe7c7d25a5ce9f282f66f

Comment: @YuriyS  its start from equation no  14, I understand till eq 38, after that i am pretty much lost.